# Find Element By 2 Tag in a Div

Tags: html, json, selenium, tags, getelementbyid

I want to find  value but value is always changing. And name="customerNum" is unique. So I want to use that 2 tag. But when I try, I got error. What is the way to use this 2 tag with "and" maybe.

```
<div class="gtstep-input-inner">
  <input name="customerNum" type="text">
  <input type="hidden" value="638367795">
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to use like  //div(//input[@name='customerNum'] and //input[@type="hidden"]). But it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by `2 Tag`? Which element do you want exactly? If you are looking for the `type=hidden`, then this is working for me: `//input[@type='hidden']`;  likewise, if you are looking for `name=customerNum`, then this works for me: `//input[@name='customerNum']`. If you want to get all the elements with `input`, you can use `//input` this gives you 2 elements, and then you can traverse each element with a `for` loop.

Comment: @AnandGautam I want to get value tag. value="638367795". But value always changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='hidden']").get_attribute('value')
print(x)
```

Output:

```
638367795

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you said the value changes, it will fetch the value at that point in time (when the line is executed)

If you just want to get that element and not the value in it, then use this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='hidden']")
```

As per your html in your query, this works to get the input element that has value attribute, i.e., the second input element